# Emacs print margin column

Tags: emacs

is there any way to show a *real* print margin at a specific column (e.g. 80), such that the background gets another color for columns above "n" or a solid line is shown at this column?

I found `ColumnMarker` (see [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker)), unfortunately, this addon only highlights text that is beyond the specified column.

What I've also tried is changing the window/frame size of emacs to (w/h) = (80/). 
Generally, this works pretty fine. Unfortunately, it doesn't under GNOME, if the emacs window/frame is maximized!

Comment: I like highlight-80+ for that. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344474/how-can-i-make-emacs-highlight-lines-that-go-over-80-chars).

Answer (score 7):

The package fill-column-indicator.el does exactly what you want, it draws a vertical line at the fill-margin column, but can be configured to use a different value (wrap code comments at column 70, display the vertical line at column 80).

The EmacsWiki has the file and configuration tips.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/FillColumnIndicator

Comment: Works for me! I installed by (1) creating directory `~/emacs.d/lisp`, (2) copying the file displayed at `https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator/blob/master/fill-column-indicator.el` to new file `~/emacs.d/lisp/fill-column-indicator.el`, and (3) adding to my `~/.emacs` file the following lines: `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")` and `(require 'fill-column-indicator)` and `(define-globalized-minor-mode global-fci-mode fci-mode (lambda () (fci-mode 1)))` and `(global-fci-mode 1)`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, there is no way to set a different background to the right of the end-of-line (which I think is what you are trying to do). You can set a background color for each frame, and override it only for normal displayed characters.

My information is a little dated, so it's possible that the impossibility is only in Emacs <=22 and Emacs 23 introduces a way.

Answer (score 0):

Add `(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^[^\n]\\{80\\}\\(.*\\)$" 1 font-lock-warning-face t)))` to your mode hook and it will change the font lock after the 80th column.

Comment: Thx, that's a nice idea, but that's exactly what ColumnMarker and its pendants do and not exactly what i meant.
What I would like to have is a solid line _across_ all visible lines at column #80, just like every other valuable ide has it nowadays (e.g. eclipse, see here: http://img844.imageshack.us/i/printmargin.png/).