# How can I make emacs highlight lines that go over 80 chars?

Tags: emacs

I know there are solutions to making emacs show the 80 line column, but I don't want that sort of visual disturbance. I'd just like to make it highlight a line if it's over 80 characters.

Comment: > _I know there are solutions_ For those who don't know, e.g. https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillColumnIndicator . That might not have existed when the question was asked and is not too disturbing IMHO, but taste is, well, a matter of taste.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Another easy option is to run `highlight-lines-matching-regexp` on the expression `.\{81\}`.

Every line with 81 characters or more will be highlighted with the color of your choice.

Comment: Brilliant. Is there any way I can enable this in my .emacs?

Comment: Highlighting is a per-buffer setting. However you can add a mode-specific hook on your .emacs like this: `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook '(lambda () (highlight-lines-matching-regexp ".\{81\}" "hi-green-b")))`. I didn't find a generic new-buffer-hook to work on all buffers.

Comment: Why doesn't `(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook '(lambda () (highlight-lines-matching-regexp ".\{81\}" "hi-green-b")))` work for me?

Comment: @RNAer Try this: `(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook '(lambda () (highlight-lines-matching-regexp ".\\{81\\}" 'hi-yellow)))`

Comment: @Juancho [`find-file-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Visiting-Functions.html#Visiting-Functions) should be the hook you were looking for.

Comment: @Juancho: Why I had to have `".\\{81\\}"` instead of `".\{81\}"`?

Comment: highlight-regexp will do something similar, but can also highlight arbitrary regexps in parts of lines.  highlight-regexp ^.\{81\}.*$ would highlight the whole line, if you wanted that.

Comment: @Alex: Emacs in general, and your `.emacs` can do **anything**: https://www.xkcd.com/378/

Comment: If you "solve" the problem (you apply `fill-paragraph` for instance), the highlight will still be present. Any way to recalculate it at each change?

Answer (score 33):

See [`whitespace-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) -- it's now part of Emacs, and can do much more than highlighting just long lines.  (But of course can be used to do only that.)

Comment: Can you explain how this works? There's an oblique reference to "long lines", but on explanation of what makes a line long. If it's not 80 characters, how do you specify 80?

Comment: You can set the `whitespace-line-column`.  For more options, use `M-x customize-group RET whitespace RET` and you'll see all of them.  (I just look at the source and write the elisp code...)

Comment: I used redspace.el (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/redspace.el), but this seems better. Thanks!

Comment: My problem with this is it adds a bunch of other highlighting which is likely not needed.

Comment: @EoghanM, look at `whitespace-style`: you can control what to highlight.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my config from [Emacs Dev Kit](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-dev-kit):

```
;; whitespace-mode
;; free of trailing whitespace and to use 80-column width, standard indentation
(setq whitespace-style '(trailing lines space-before-tab
                                  indentation space-after-tab)
      whitespace-line-column 80)
```

Basically you need just the last bit, but I find the other settings quite useful (I hate tabs and trailing whitespaces).

Answer (score 5):

Try `highlight-80+.el`. You can acquire it from [here](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-80+/).

To install it, just add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/highlight-80+")
(require 'highlight-80+)
```

You can then enable it via:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `highlight-80+-mode`

Comment: The author of *highlight-80+.el* says its discontinued and recommends, since Emacs 23, to use *whitespace-mode*'s *whitespace-line-column*.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you wanted, but I had a similar problem and found this question/answer. All I wanted was to insert a visual guide, when I needed it. This is what I finally ended up with:

```
(defun insert-80 ()
    "Insert an 80-character-wide guide at beginning of line."
    (interactive)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (insert "0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         |")
    (newline)
    (insert "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789|")
    (newline)
)
```

Super simple, but sometimes very effective.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in package in `emacs-goodies-el`(recommend to install it in terminal) called [highlight-beyond-fill-column.el](https://github.com/ncrohn/emacs/blob/master/vendor/emacs-goodies-el/highlight-beyond-fill-column.el), add this to your `.emacs` or `init.el`:

```
(setq-default fill-column 80)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'highlight-beyond-fill-column)
(custom-set-faces '(highlight-beyond-fill-column-face
                    ((t (:foreground "red" )))))
```

The text beyond `fill-column` which is 80 in the snippet will be highlighted with the color of `red`. You can set the face as you like.

Comment: Maybe using `set-face-attribute`? `custom-set-faces` are not supposed to be touched manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example code which will highlight text that lies beyond column 80 with the current 'warning' face, and a line to enable it for C++ mode.

```
;; Turn on warn highlighting for characters outside of the 'width' char limit
(defun font-lock-width-keyword (width)
  "Return a font-lock style keyword for a string beyond width WIDTH
   that uses 'font-lock-warning-face'."
  `((,(format "^%s\\(.+\\)" (make-string width ?.))
     (1 font-lock-warning-face t))))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode (font-lock-width-keyword 80))
```

It doesn't highlight the whole line, but I find it is reasonably helpful.

Comment: Doesn't work with tabs, though. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EightyColumnRule for a more advanced regexp.

Comment: Can I apply this for a specific file name pattern instead of `*mode`? @acm

Comment: @alper - Beyond my knowledge, unfortunately. Maybe start a new question?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to other answers here, with the advantage of using `fill-column`, and it runs *after* the mode switches. So each mode can have it's own line-width which is properly respected by the highlighting.

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
      (let ((column-re (format "^[^\n]\\{%d\\}\\(.*\\)$" fill-column)))
        (font-lock-add-keywords nil
          `((,column-re 1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)))))))
```

You may wan't to remove the `prog-mode` check if you like this to be enabled for text files too.