# How can I load highlight-lines-matching-regexp automatically in emacs?

Tags: emacs, hook, highlight, lines

I'm highlighting lines that go over 80 characters with

```
M-x highlight-lines-matching-regexp RET .\{81\} RET hi-yellow RET
```

I would like emacs to enable this for all my buffers automatically.

I tried

```
(add-hook 'after-load-functions
          '(lambda () ('highlight-lines-matching-regexp ".\{81\}" 'hi-yellow)))
```

as written in [How can I make emacs highlight lines that go over 80 chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344474/how-can-i-make-emacs-highlight-lines-that-go-over-80-chars) but it does not work. It says

```
run-hook-with-args: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (highlight-lines-matching-regexp ".{81}" (quote hi-yellow))), 1
```

How do I tell emacs to apply this to all my buffers automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made two mistakes:

1) there's an extra `'` before `highlight-lines-matching-regexp`
2) `after-load-functions` is no proper hook (in the sense, that it passes an argument to the function that is hooked into `after-load-functions`)

You should use this (or a similar hook, you can find an incomplete list of hooks in [the reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html)):

```
(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook '(lambda () (highlight-lines-matching-regexp ".\\{81\\}" 'hi-yellow)))
```

Assuming you only want this in programming modes you might want to use `prog-mode-hook` instead of `change-major-mode-hook` (this only works for emacs version >= 24).